# How to disable Serilog to log one exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, serilog

(Asp.Net core 3.1/.Net 6)
I need to disable the ERR logging of exception `TaskCanceledException` in an Asp.Net application (built by others). I've used the following middleware to suppress the TaskCanceledException

```
app.UseMiddleware<TaskCanceledMiddleware>();

public class TaskCanceledMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public TaskCanceledMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException)
        {
            // Set StatusCode 499 Client Closed Request
            logger.WARN("...")
            context.Response.StatusCode = 499;
        }
    }
}
```

I can see the WARN log in the logs. However, I can still find the following EROR messages by `Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware`? (Note the error level is `EROR`)

```
2022-07-06 07:30:40.6636|116344477|EROR|Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware|HTTP "GET" "/api/v1/myurl" responded 500 in 23213.3233 ms
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at ....
```

Why there is still errors of `TaskCanceledException` after using `app.UseMiddleware<TaskCanceledMiddleware>()`? (BTW, what's the level of EROR? Shouldn't it be ERR?)

Comment: I think that serilog middleware is executed before your middleware.

Comment: I searched the code and didn't find any code of use midware of serilog. Very strange

Comment: You'll have `UseSerilogRequestLogging()` in there somewhere; reordering it with respect to your `TaskCanceledMiddleware` should do what you need.

Answer (score 2):

you can try excluding logging for certain exception like this.

```
new LoggerConfiguration()
       ....
       .Filter.ByExcluding(logEvent => logEvent.Exception != null && logEvent.Exception.GetType() == typeof(TaskCanceledException))
       ...CreateLogger();
```

Comment: This works! Thanks, however, is it possible to log it as WARN instead?

Comment: this is completely excluding the logging for such exception. if you want to log as warning then you can still use your middleware along with this code so that it will skip logging as exception.

Answer (score 1):

do you know where the exception is thrown?
Maybe it throws not inside asp.net core action execution pipeline (where Middleware works).
You can register a filter to intercept application wide exceptions inside `.AddControllers()` registration like this:

```
 _ = services
        .AddControllers(options =>
        {
            //Global filters
            _ = options.Filters.Add<ApiGlobalExceptionFilterAttribute>();
            ///...omissis...
        })
```

Here a simple exception filter attribute implementation:

```
public sealed class ApiGlobalExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly ILogger<ApiGlobalExceptionFilterAttribute> _logger;

    public ApiGlobalExceptionFilterAttribute(ILogger<ApiGlobalExceptionFilterAttribute> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        var request = context.HttpContext?.Request;

        if (context.Exception is TaskCanceledException tcExc)
        {
            // Set StatusCode 499 Client Closed Request
            _logger.WARN("...");
            context.Result = new ErrorActionResult(499);
        }
        else
        {
            //TODO: manage errors
        }

        context.ExceptionHandled = true;

        base.OnException(context);
    }
}

internal class ErrorActionResult : IActionResult
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int StatusCode { get; private set; }

    public ErrorActionResult(int statusCode)
    {
        StatusCode = statusCode;
    }

    public async Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
    {
        var error = new
        {
            Code = StatusCode,
            Message = "Internal server error"
        };

        var objectResult = new ObjectResult(error)
        {
            StatusCode = StatusCode
        };

        await objectResult.ExecuteResultAsync(context);
    }
}
```

The `context.ExceptionHandled = true;` stops exception to be propagated inside pipeline.

Hope it helps!